# Finding the top ranked object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am storing movie objects with name and rank properties inside an array
How do I find the top ranked object?

Comment: Can you give us a code example of what you actually have? The object representation?

Comment: If you have an array of objects that are something like: `{name: "foo", rank: 1}` then you can simply  sort by the rank property in descending mode and take the first object of the array. Check [this](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-by-property-javascript/) out.

Comment: [ {name : 'A', rank: 1}, {name : 'B', rank : 2}, {name : 'C', rank:3} ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce`

```js
let array = [{"name":"XYZ","rank":1},{"name":"ABC","rank":2}];
let max = array.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return (prev.rank > current.rank) ? prev : current
})

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution to the reduce concept. It returns an array of movie objects (because: usually two or more movies can have the same rank).

```js
const movies = [
    { name: 'Avatar', rank: 95 },
    { name: 'Harry Potter', rank: 80 },
    { name: 'Lord of the Rings 1', rank: 95 },
];

const movieRanks = movies.map((movie) => { return movie.rank; });
const highestMovieRank = Math.max(... movieRanks);
const highestRankedMovies = movies.filter((movie) => { return movie.rank === highestMovieRank});

// first occurence is the highest ranked movie
const highestRankedMovie = highestRankedMovies[0];

console.log(highestRankedMovies);
```

Comment: Top ranked would be #1.

Answer (score -1):

Hi There This one may help you:

```
function FindTopRankedMovie(movies){
let topRankIndex=0;
for(let i=1;i<movies.length;i++)
     {
      /*here we loop all the array and compare the ranks and keep 
      highest rank in topRankIndex variables and return it at the end */       
     if(movies[i].getRank>movies[topRankIndex].getRank)
        topRankIndex=i;

     }
 return topRankIndex;
}
```

> in main page you use the function as :

---

```
let top=FindTopRankedMovie(movies); 
echo "The top ranked Movie is"+movies[top];
```